# If range of cells contains specific text, replace last character in different cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 150 csv files with similar data to what is in the image.

The first table is the original data, the second table is what I would like, and the third table contains information needed in order to do the edits.

The numbers at the end of each cell are based on the acronyms in AF-AO.

I am trying to replace the numbers at the end of the cells in row 1 based on the text that is in row 2.

In the third table, the numbers next to the acronyms are what I need the numbers at the end of all the cells to be.

Examples:

Cell AF2 contains "AAS" and in the above cell, the number is 1. I want to change all number 1s in the first row to 2, since AAS has a 2 beside it in the third table.

Cell AI2 contains "ICP" and in the above cell, the number is 2. I want to change all number 2s in the first row to 3, because ICPMS has a 2 beside it in the third table.

The examples are for this table only, each of the 150 csv files are different.

In all of my csv files, the numbers at the end of the cells are not consistent, i.e AAS is not always associated with 1. The columns with the acronyms are not always in AF-AO. The headers are also not always the same, there may be ME_Digestion_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, etc. So, I need some kind of code that is very open to these different possibilities.

I really have no idea how to do this, so any help is appreciated. I can clarify anything if I did not explain this well enough.

[image: example]

Comment: Your question consists of a lot of sub-tasks. Is there only one instance of the third table, which all 150 CSVs use? Or does each CSV have its own "third table"? In the image, cell X1 ends with 2, but cell X16 ends with 3. Why? Are there more rows in your third table than are shown in the image? Column `X` does not appear to contain any acronyms that correspond to the third table (in fact it appears to contain numeric values).

Comment: There is only 1 instance of the 3rd table and all 150 CSVs will use it. There might be more rows eventually. This is geochemical data. "ME" = multi-element and includes all elements except for Au, As, Hg, S which is why these 4 elements will have their own "Digestion, Analysis and Aliquot Size column (Hg and S are not present in the example). So, in the first table, cell X1 ends with a 2 because Cu is included in the ME, multi-element, suite. In the first table, the 2 is associated with ICP (cell AI) and since in table 3, ICP is associated with the number 3, cell A16 ends with a 3.

Comment: All of the tables contain geochemical data and the numbers at the end of the element cells corresponds to information (digestion, analysis and aliquot size) about those elements. Eventually, all of these data will be merged together and so I want to be able to easily filter the data by, for example, the analysis. 

The example is an extremely simplified version of all of the data, but basically I just want the analyses associated with the numbers consistent, and they are not at this point.